# How to persist data after Windows Phone 8.1 App update from the store?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8, windows-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I will have a pre-installed App in a device with version 2.0
If the user updates the App to version 2.1 by downloading it from the Windows store,  i want to still know that the user originally had the pre-installed app. (it is a special kind of user which had the app installed when he bought the phone).

How can i persist data between updates?
Does isolated storage work for this case?

Answer (score 3):

Updating app does not delete data in Isolated Storage. (that would be terrible thing :) )